# JSQMessagesViewController get current text

Tags: ios, jsqmessagesviewcontroller

Anyone know how you get the current text of a JSQMessagesViewController?  When the view disappears I wan to cache the text the user has typed in so that when they return I can repopulate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it.

self.inputToolbar.contentView.textView.text!